# compiler error `FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h' file not found` (Facebook api graph 2 + Parse.com)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

The SDK (v 4.0) is no longer one framework named "FacebookSDK", but rather a few different packages with a naming convention of "FBSDKTypeKit", where types are different things like Core and Login.

I'm using the Parse.com SDK to handle all my users Facebook login.
but now, when I installed the new Facebook SDK (4.0) and the Parse.com SDK as well, I get a compiler error `FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h' file not found`.
I guess that the Parse.com SDK is not updated to work with the new Facebook SDK in 100%, but maybe someone can tell me if there is and solution for this situation?

Comment: Check this link : Parse has given the support for Facebook SDK v4.0 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/2XNfK0KVF9s